# Drawing slope signature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, slope, geometry-generator

I would like to have a slope signature (in German "Böschungsschraffen") like this :

- https://bauforum.wirklichewelt.de/index.php?id=9672 (German)
- https://www.akgsoftware.de/docs/de/infravision/b56/akgcad/webhelp/topics/boeschung_c_grundlagen.html (German)
- https://resources.geooffice.vertigis.com/documentation/DE/topographie/index.html?boeschungssignaturen_-_tool.htm (German)

There are long and short lines going from a upper level to a lower level representing the slope.

I just want to draw the signature outgoing from an upper-level line to the lower-level line. I tried it with simple Marker-Line-Symbology but this is not working on edges as marked with red arrows. Maybe the Geometry Generator could do the job, but it seems very advanced.

This is a gravel pit where I tried "Böschungsschraffen" but the red arrows shows the problems I got:
[image]

Comment: To me, it's not 100% clear what the problem is and what exactly you want to achieve. Lines from one black line to the other one? What abotu the green line? Does it matter or not? Can you provide sample data?

Comment: The green line doesn't matter. In German it's called "Böschungsschraffen", I can't find a translation for it. It's used to show the direction of a slope from the upper contour to the lower one. Here are more details, how it is used: https://www.akgsoftware.de/docs/de/infravision/b56/akgcad/webhelp/topics/boeschung_c_grundlagen.html

Comment: Could you provide more details about what conditions the lines should fulfill (the solution provided does not seem to be what you're looking for) as well as based on what kind of data (two line layers? maybe you can provide sample data?) the solution should work?

Comment: It is difficult to explain with words, but if you look at the images by following the links in my question, you will see what i'm looking for. The solution you provided comes very close, but the problems in the "inner-edges" are still there (polygon 1, 2 and 3 of your example). The kind of layers doesn't matter - line or polygon.

Comment: Those lines are called hachures, and are often used to mark depression contours. Though the standard hachures used in the US are more simple than the Boschungsschraffen. http://academic.brooklyn.cuny.edu/geology/leveson/core/linksa/depression.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Automatic solution

I created a model that automatically creates the lines as you want as a layer style. Run the model, make the inputs and you get the style you want. Details about how I did it: see below.

When running the model, you need to define 5 inputs: an inner (1) and an outer (2) vector layer (polygons or lines), the interval between the lines you want to create (3) and the files used for styling the output inner layer (4: these are the lines you want) and outer (5, no style at all) layers. The two style files (4 and 5) are included in the zip file together with the model itself, you can download everything here: https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/i6AkSCXxLFSNXxX

*You can avoid having to define the two style files if you define them in the model: hardcode the path to the two style files. For this, change the two `Set layer style` entries and instead of `Model input` change to `Value` and enter your path/filename. Then delete the `inner style` and `outer style` inputs.*

[image]

#### Solution: the prinicple

To get correct lines at corners you must combine two styles: one for "outward/convex" corners, one for "inward/concave" corners. Create points at regular intervals on inner and outer polygon boundary, then first create the line from each point of the inner layer to the closest point of the outer layer. Second, identify those points of the outer layer that have not yet been connected and create additional lines from these points to the closest point of the inner layer.

*Solution, connecting red (inner) and blue (outer) points - combination of two symbol layer of type Geometry generator:*

[image]

#### Step by step

Use QGIS expressions with geometry generator.

1. Create points at regular intervals along the boundary of the inner and outer polygons, thus creating two point layers `inner` and `outer`. Use e.g. [Points along geometry](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgispointsalonglines) tool or this expression with [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) (and run [Multipart to single parts](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=multipart#multipart-to-singleparts)), where `2` is the interval (change this to fit your needs):

   ```
   collect_geometries (
       array_foreach (
           generate_series (0, length(boundary ($geometry)), 2),
           line_interpolate_point (boundary($geometry), @element)
       )
   )
   ```

   *Result: points layers `inner` (red) and `outer` (blue):*
   [image]
2. Create slope lines from each point of the inner layer to the closest point of the outer layer with this expression (e.g. with [Geometry Generator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html#hard-fa-geometry-generator-symbology)) and change `outer` to the layer name you use:

   ```
    with_variable (
        'line',
        make_line (
            $geometry,
            overlay_nearest ('outer',$geometry)[0]
        ),
        line_substring (@line,0, length(@line)*($id%2+1 )/2)
    )
   ```

   *If you want the half lines to start from the outer layer, change the second last line to: `line_substring (@line, length(@line)*($id%2+0)/2, length(@line))`*

   *Result: lines from all red points to the closest blue point:*

   [image]
3. After the first part, you now need to create lines from the points on the outer layer that have not been used yet. Add another symbol layer of type Geometry generator with this expression (again replacing `outer` with the layer name you use) - see below for explanation:

   ```
    case when $id= minimum ($id) then 
    collect_geometries(
        with_variable(
            'array',
            array_foreach (
                array_foreach ( 
                    array_filter(
                        array_foreach (
                            aggregate ('outer', 'array_agg', $id),
                            if (
                                array_contains( 
                                    array_agg (overlay_nearest ('outer',$id)[0]),
                                    @element
                                ),
                                '',
                                @element
                            )
                        ), 
                        @element<>''
                    ),
                    geometry (
                        get_feature_by_id(
                            'outer',
                            @element
                        )
                    )
                ),
                make_line (
                    @element,
                    closest_point (
                        collect( $geometry),
                        @element
                    )
                )
            ),
            array_foreach (
                generate_series (0, array_length( @array)-1),
                line_substring(
                    @array[@element],
                    length (@array[@element])*(@element%2+0)/2, 
                    length(@array[@element])
                )
            )
        )
    )
    end
   ```

   Result: lines in red (color for visualization only to see the difference from lines created before): they connect blue points not yet connected in step 2 above with the closest red point:

   [image]

**Variant:**

To change the half-size lines of step 3 to be outgoing from the outer line (not the inner), change the `line_substring()` part of the above expression (9th last to 5th last line) like this:

```
line_substring(
    @array[@element],
    0,
    length (@array[@element])*(@element%2+1)/2
)
```

[image]

#### Explanation of step 3 from above

1. For performance reasons, just run the expression once and not repeatedly for each feature as it would return the same output for each feature. Use a `case ... when` condition (line 1) with `$id= minimum ($id)` - so just for the first feature you have.
2. Get all features form the outer (blue) layer: create an array of all id's of each point from the `outer` layer using `aggregate ('outer', 'array_agg', $id)` (line 9)
3. Get all features of the outer (blue) layer that are connected in the first round (step 2 above) with this expression: `array_agg (overlay_nearest ('outer',$id)[0])` (line 12)
4. Use `array_contains()` (line 11) with `array_foreach()` (line 8) to check for each point from step 1 if it is contained in the points from step 2
5. Use the ids returned in step 3 (ids of the outer/blue points not that have not been connected in the first round) with `geometry()` and `get_feature_by_id()` (lines 21-22) to convert the id to the features's point geometry.
6. Use this point to make a line connecting it to the closest point on the inner (red) layer using `make_line ()` (line 28)
7. Use a `line_substring()` function (line 38) similar to the one above to create alternating full and half lines. Add another `array_foreach ()` (line 36) to create alternating values of 1 and 0.5 (end of line 40)

Comment: Nearly perfect! But how can I change the half-size lines of step 3 to be outgoing from the outer line (not the inner)?

Comment: See updated answer, part "Variant" for this.

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to start making the lines form the outer line to the inner line. Create regular points along the outer line with a regular interval. Then create a line from each of these points to the closest point of the inner line (or polygon). Finally, alternate line length based between even and uneven points (or elements/array-index, using `array_foreach()` function).

[image]

The expression looks like:

```
with_variable (
    'dist',
    2, -- interval to create lines
    collect_geometries (
        array_foreach (
            generate_series (1,length (boundary($geometry))/@dist),
            with_variable (
                'point',
                line_interpolate_point (boundary($geometry), @dist*@element),
                with_variable(
                    'line',
                    make_line (
                        @point,
                        closest_point (
                            overlay_nearest ('Buffered',$geometry)[0],
                            @point
                        )
                    ),
                    line_substring (
                        @line,
                        0,
                        if (
                            @element%2=0, 
                            length (@line),
                            length (@line)*0.5 -- length of shorter lines, value from 0 to 1
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

To generate the lines based on the inner (blue) layer, adapt the expression as follows

[image]

```
with_variable (
    'dist',
    2, -- interval to create lines
    collect_geometries (
        array_foreach (
            generate_series (1,length (boundary($geometry))/@dist),
            with_variable (
                'point',
                line_interpolate_point (boundary($geometry), @dist*@element),
                with_variable(
                    'line',
                    make_line (
                        @point,
                        closest_point (
                            boundary(overlay_nearest ('pol',$geometry)[0]),
                            @point
                    )
                    ),
                    line_substring (
                        @line,
                        
                        if (
                            @element%2=0, 
                            0,length (@line)/2 -- length of shorter lines, value from 0 to 1
                            
                        ),length (@line)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```